# Apache 2.2.14: SSLCARevocation location

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, httpd.conf, revoked

I am installing a .crl in my apache config. It looks like this:

VirtualHost *default*

DocumentRoot "web"
ServerName example.com

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile "cert.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "key.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "cert.ca-bundle"

SSLProtocol -all +SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite SSLv3:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

Directory

Order deny,allow
Allow from all

SSLCACertificateFile "ClientRootCert.crt"

SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 3

SSLCARevocationFile "CRLList.crl"

Directory

VirtualHost

When Apache is started, I get the error:

SSLCARevocationFile not allowed here

When I place SSLCARevocationFile above the Directory tag, Apache starts, but all client certs are rejected with the message:

ssl_error_expired_cert_alert (both revoked and active certs)

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have already found the answer but I may help someone else.
I have had the same error because I generated my crl with this parameter : "crl_hours 1". 1 hour after the crl creation, the error appears.

If you didn't use this parameter, check the "default_crl_days" of your "openssl.conf" and compare it to the date of last update of the crl.